# Dell XPS M1330 does not want to restore to factory settings

Tags: windows-vista, dell-xps

I have tried restarting and then pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> - there are no options for restore - there is just reboot in safe mode, reboot with debugging etc.

I have also tried restarting and then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> which does nothing.

I have done this many times before but I think its a problem now because I installed Windows Vista Prof over the original Vista Home.

I can still see the restore partition in My Computer though.

Any ideas?  I can't find any Windows CD either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory restore on a Vista system is different than on a Windows XP system. You need your Reinstall disk(!) and follow the instructions [HERE](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_298A2E89689E13C2E040A68F5B280AA4&isLegacy=true).

I would say you are screwed then!